# Any good free formal logic PDFs?

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am having a heck of a time Googling for this. But I want to learn the same kind of formal logic you might learn when studying for a computer science or math degree. Problem is I don't even know what I should be looking for. Prepositional logic? Boolean logic? Predicate logic? First order logic? Second order logic? Discrete mathematics? Something else?

I am just looking to get an all-around understanding of logic so I can be more literate in that area since it underlies so much else.

Are there any good resources for learning all of these things that doesn't require spending a ton of money or reading thousands of pages? Decent PDFs would be ideal if they exist.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "How to Prove It" and "How To Think Like a Mathematician" might be what you're looking for.

Comment: So.. like... what are you in to? I ask because it would be nice to know what you are looking to get out of a particular reference, or more importantly what you'd be bringing to the table as you dive into a text. (there are a lot of decent texts/pdfs/open-textbook projects; however some are tailored for particular audiences.)

Comment: May I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with my DC Proof freeware that you can download from my homepage at http://www,dcproof.com It is a mathematically oriented introduction to the basic methods of proof including propositional and predicate logic. An easy to use proof checker is also included to give you immediate feedback on exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you decide what you want, you might try this [Teach Yourself Logic Study Guide](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2017.pdf) (i.e. heavily annotated reading list). Only the first few chapters will be relevant -- ignore the more advanced stuff.

An update: one of the top-recommended books, the *Friendly Guide to Mathematical Logic*, is now freely available as a PDF. A number of other recommendations are also freely (and officially!) available too